# find condition that is fulfilled with a tree of conditions

Tags: python

(sorry for the title, part of the problem is my lack of knowledge about the right keywords.)

I am looking for a design for the following problem:

Given a list of items (with different attributes), depending on what items appear, I want to run different code:

```
if len(items) == 1 and A(items[0]):
    return X(items)
elif len(items) == 1 and B(items[0]):
    return Y(items)
elif len(items) == 2 and C(items) and D(items):
    return Z(items)
else:
    raise NotImplementedError
```

(`A, B, C, D` can be simple like evaluating the type of an item, but it can require recursively evaluating an expression (e.g. is `items[0] = Expression("((x + y) - z)") is a string or a number?`)).

So far, I use `elif`, tons of them. But as you can already observe, there are conditions that are repeated multiple times, and the code is difficult to read.

The second thing I tried was to put the second condition separated from the first, e.g.

```
if len(items) == 1:
    if A(items[0]):
        return X(items)
    elif B(items[0]):
        return Y(items)
...
```

However, even though there are certain conditions that are highly informative for the decision (e.g. `len(items) == 1`), and thus make sense to make them the outermost condition, they can be from very different areas of the project (e.g. code for UI and code for backend).

I suspect I need to name each condition and construct a kind of a tree with them, but I am not finding the right keyword for searching this in google and SO.

How is this type of problem solved?

**EDIT:** context: I am implementing this to interpret a scripting language. Essentially, when the interpreter comes across an expression, e.g. "x + y" or "x * y" or "call z", I need to convert it to the respective action in the other language. The particular action depends on the type of the variable (e.g. if `x` and `y` are strings or numbers) and number of arguments (e.g. default arguments). In most cases the type is only known at execution time (e.g. if `x` is itself an expression, in which case I am using a recursion to evaluate it). The number of functions is also large, thus there is the need for a large number of `elif`.

Comment: Is `A(items[0])` some function or `A()` is it just to check the type of `items[0]`?

Comment: Also, is `C(items) and D(items)` correct, or you meant `C(items[0]) and D(items[1])`?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, sorry, I just edited the question to clarify. No, A can be more complicated like recursively evaluating an expression and deciding its type.

Comment: OOP could be a possible solution by using inheritance and localize common functions in base class(es). Could you provide more details on how your code will be used from the main part ?

Comment: Is the decision rules are constant =  1 test len(), 2 test function, ... then result-function ?

Comment: @J.Piquard thanks for the comments. I have added some context to the question to clarify the goal of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposal of solution to manage multiple case tests and action and to reduce the number of `elif`.
The solution is based to a `namedtuple` and a simple `Parse` function.

**Step 1** - import and declare the `namedtuple P_`.

```
from collections import namedtuple
P_ = namedtuple("Parser", ["len", "test", "action"])
```

1. The field `"len"` is used to managed `if len(items) == 1:`,
2. The field `"test"` contains a list of function pointers to managed `if A(items[0]):`,
3. The field `"action"` contains function pointer to be executed as `return X(items)`,

**Step 2** - define the `Parse()` function to analyse the input list `items` and execute the `action` when implemented.

```
def Parse(m_struct, m_list):
    # explore all namedtuple P_
    for m_parse in m_struct:
        # check is the "len" parameter matches
        if len(m_list) == m_parse.len:
            # execute the list of "test" functions
            for m_test in m_parse.test:
                if m_test(m_list) == False:
                    # at the first False => return
                    return
            # otherwise execute the action
            m_parse.action(m_list)
            return
    # to be replaced by a real 'raise NotImplementedError'
    print("raise NotImplementedError")
```

**Step 3** - define the array of `namedtuple P_` to be explored

```
mParsers = [
    P_(len = 1, test = [ A ], action = X),
        # if len(items) == 1 and A(items[0]):
        #     return X(items)
    P_(len = 1, test = [ B ], action = Y),
        # elif len(items) == 1 and B(items[0]):
        #     return Y(items)
    P_(len = 2, test = [ C, D ], action = Z)
        # elif len(items) == 2 and C(items) and D(items):
        #     return Z(items)
]
```

**Step 4** - series of "test" functions (to be replaced by the real ones)

```
def A(lst_items):
    return True

def B(lst_items):
    return False

def C(lst_items):
    return True

def D(lst_items):
    return False
```

**Step 5** - series of "action" functions (to be replaced by the real ones)

```
def X(lst_items):
    print('X=>',lst_items)
    return

def Y(lst_items):
    print('Y=>',lst_items)
    return

def Z(lst_items):
    print('Z=>',lst_items)
    return
```

**Step 4** - how to call the parser

```
print("- list[1]")
Parse(mParsers,[1])
# output
# - list[1]
# X=> [1] ... action executed
print("- list[1, 2]")
Parse(mParsers,[1, 2])
# output
# - list[1, 2] ... 1 test is False = no action
print("- list[1, 2, 3]")
Parse(mParsers,[1, 2, 3])
# output
# - list[1, 2, 3]
# raise NotImplementedError = Exception for a list of 3 items
```